# call Oracle stored procedure with array output argument from Java

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, plsql, callable-statement

I have a problem will calling plsql procedure from Java. Package with procedure is below:  (schema `job_runner` and connection user/scheme is not same):

```
create or replace package  test_package_for_sp as

  type some_record_type is record
  (
      field_number      number,
      field_varchar2    varchar2 (128),
      field_date        date
  );

  type some_table_type is table of some_record_type;


  procedure proc_table (p_card_bin    in     varchar2,
                        p_date        in     date default null,
                        p_out_table      out some_table_type);
}
```

And then I try to call it from Java with callableStatement:

```
    final String typeTableList = "SOME_TABLE_TYPE";

    CallableStatement cs = null;
    try (Connection con = dataSource.getConnection()) {
        con.setSchema("JOB_RUNNER");

        cs = con.prepareCall("{call job_runner.test_package_for_sp.proc_table(?, ?, ?)}");

        cs.setString(1, "54867321");
        cs.setDate(2, Date.valueOf(ZonedDateTime.now().minusDays(200).toLocalDate()));
        cs.registerOutParameter(3, Types.ARRAY, typeTableList);

        cs.execute();
    } finally {
        if (cs != null)
            cs.close();
    }
```

Error raise:

```
java.sql.SQLException: invalid name pattern: <connection_scheme>.SOME_TABLE_TYPE

    at oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleTypeADT.initMetadata11_2(OracleTypeADT.java:764)
    at oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleTypeADT.initMetadata(OracleTypeADT.java:479)
    at oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleTypeADT.init(OracleTypeADT.java:443)
```

If I change value in `typeTableLis` from value `SOME_TABLE_TYPE` to 
full path with package and scheme `JOB_RUNNER.TEST_PACKAGE_FOR_SP.SOME_TABLE_TYPE` exception change to:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01948: identifier's name length (35) exceeds maximum (30)
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_PICKLER", line 18
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_PICKLER", line 58
ORA-06512: at line 1


    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:494)
```

Does anybody know how to call this procedure from java?

Comment: 1) Create your type as SQL type ("create type some_record_type as object (..);") 2) Use oracle java arraydescriptor, to identify and pass the type in your procedure;

Comment: @Ychdziu Arraydescriptor internally is called (at oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor(ArrayDescriptor.java:79)). And this class is deprecated. Could you past some example how to identify and pass type from arraydescriptor to procedure?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the JDBC connection property `"oracle.jdbc.createDescriptorUseCurrentSchemaForSchemaName"` to `"true"`, then switch the schema to `"job_runner"` (`ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA=job_runner`) and use `TEST_PACKAGE_FOR_SP.SOME_TABLE_TYP` for typeTableList.

Comment: Thanks to comment, but this same not working. Error is: `java.sql.SQLException: invalid name pattern: TEST_PACKAGE_FOR_SP.SOME_TABLE_TYPE

 at oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleTypeADT.initMetadata11_2(OracleTypeADT.java:764)
 at oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleTypeADT.initMetadata(OracleTypeADT.java:479)
 at oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleTypeADT.init(OracleTypeADT.java:443)
 at oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor.initPickler(ArrayDescriptor.java:1499)`

Comment: Which version of the driver are you using? 11.2 or 12.1 or 12.2? 18c maybe? Do java -jar ojdbcX.jar to find out.

Comment: driver version: 12.2.0.1

Comment: I suspect the database version is older than that (12.2) because the max length of an identifier in Oracle was extended from 30 to 128 in 12.2. What's your database version?

Comment: yes, oracle 11.2.0.4.0. Thanks, it seems to be related to this.

Answer (score 0):

One of the approach:

```
package testproject;

import java.sql.Array;
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Types;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import oracle.sql.ARRAY;

import oracle.jdbc.OracleCallableStatement;

import oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor;

    public class MainClass {
    public MainClass() {
        super();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainClass mainClass = new MainClass();

        Connection conn = null;

        ArrayDescriptor des = null;

        try {

            Object[] obj1 = { 1, "2017-01-01 10:12:10", 200 };
            Object[] obj2 = { 2, "2017-06-01 10:12:10", 600 };
            Object[] obj3 = { 3, "2017-08-01 10:12:10", 990 };

            conn =
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@<DB_HOST>",
                            "<user>", "<pass>");

          try {
              des = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("AJ_TEST_OBJ_TBL", conn);
          } catch (SQLException e) {
              System.out.println("Arraydesc went wrong.");
              System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
          }

          ARRAY nArray =
              new ARRAY(des, conn, new Object[] { obj1, obj2, obj3 });

            OracleCallableStatement pstmt =
                (OracleCallableStatement)conn.prepareCall("begin 
aj_test_array_pck.print_tbl_parameters(?,?); end;");

            pstmt.setArray(1, nArray);
            pstmt.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR);
            pstmt.execute();

            String status = pstmt.getString(2);
            System.out.println("Status: " + status);

            pstmt.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Oops with select");
            System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Oops with class");
        }
    }

}
```

where "AJ_TEST_OBJ_TBL" is a SQL type object.

Comment: Yes, I saw this example somethere, but it has example with `IN` array param, not `OUT` as I needed.

Comment: And as I say before, `ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor` has been called internally

Comment: The in parameter is the defined array, the out is just a simple varchar, with outcomes E/S, just to see, if the procedure did its job.

Comment: The main aspect is, to define your type not as a PL/SQL type, but as a SQL type.